# Multiple linklists on shopify categories (sidebar)

Tags: shopify

Yet another shopify question. I have a sidebar on shop/collections page

> settings.sidebar_categoryblock_linklist

Which shows links to my main collecions: men/woman/kinds ect.
Yet I have another collection list based on product tags:

> Winter/Autumn/Casual/Business etc

How do I get to display them on the sidebar? Meaning how can I put several linklists as categories link lists?

Thanks in advance
Julia

Answer (score 0):

In a collection page, you have access to all the tags (unique) that the products have. You can use these tags to see if the belong to any collection and then display them. The code is as follows:

```
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
{% assign c_collection = collections[tag] %} // c_collection is used so the current display page's collection doesn't get disturbed
{% if c_collection.title != '' %}
{{ tag | link_to: c_collection.url,c_collection.title }} // not sure about this, but you can use proper html as well here
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```